# Better name for "vendor trash"?

Tags: terminology

In many games, "vendor trash" is a term used for items that have no purpose other than to be sold to a vendor for money. What would be a better name for a class of items a GM might give to a player for that same sole purpose? I don't really like the sound of "vendor trash" used in an official item description.

Comment: Is this a table-top game related question, or a video-game one? (If the former; which game, and what are you trying to do?)

Comment: This is in regards for making my own RPG.

Comment: A paper & pencil RPG, like Dungeons & Dragons, or a video game RPG, like Final Fantasy or World of Warcraft?

Comment: Edit: This is definitely not in regards to making my own video game RPG that has a pen and paper theme.

Comment: That statement confuses me... what is it in regards to, then?

Comment: I've heard “supplement treadmill” but never “vendor trash”.

Comment: @okeefe supplement treadmill sounds like a zany sort of fitness spam.

Comment: Are this in-game character items or out-of-game player items?

Comment: Old & closed, but we always called this stuff "Shop food"

Comment: Why can't we re-open this, since it's not specifically about video games anymore?

Comment: It kind of bugs me that in DDO (a video game), gems are vendor trash because they take up backpack space but coins do not.

Answer (score 5):

In D&D, what you're describing are often called **trade goods**. For example, from D&D 5th edition's basic rules:

> **Trade Goods.** On the borderlands, many people conduct transactions through barter. Like gems and art objects, trade goods—bars of iron, bags of salt, livestock, and so on—retain their full value in the market and can be used as currency.

Comment: what about all the random minutia you find in dungeons?  Giant Snail slime and Minotaur horns. Maybe iron shavings?

Comment: Who's buying giant snail slime, anyway? It's not a video game, in this case...

Comment: Trade goods doesn't sound bad, but it doesn't seem like it would apply to something like the aforementioned giant snail slime, which should be worth something to somebody if the GM is giving it to you. Perhaps an alchemist. "Worth something to somebody" doesn't sound too good either.

Comment: Trade goods works fine. I won't buy a goat because it has no use to me, doesn't mean it's not a trade good. Giant snail slime and minotaur horns are also trade goods, they're just not useful to most people, but a wizard or alchemist might want to pay you for it.

Comment: Then, of course, the trick becomes figuring out who will actually buy it. Ugthar the Blacksmith has no interest in your Giant Snail Slime...and certainly isn't going to but all the cracked clay dinnerware that you looted from the bandit camp.

Comment: The other type of "loot that's there only to be sold off" are referred to in the basic rules and PHB as "***Gems, Jewelry, and Art Objects.*** These items retain their full value in the marketplace, and you can either trade them in for coin or use them as currency for other transactions. For exceptionally valuable treasures, the DM might require you to find a buyer in a large town or larger community first."

Comment: There's a difference between stuff that essentially has no purpose other than to serve as a reward that can be exchanged for gp and stuff that *can* be sold for gp but might also be useful to some clever adventurer under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Vendor Trash is typically comprised of two parts:

1. Trade Goods

   - Trade Goods (goods that are traded) tend to be consumable items and are often acquired and bought/sold in bulk. This term could also be used to refer to items that are used in *a Trade* such as ore for blacksmithing and hides for tanning/leathercraft. Generally speaking (without knowing a specific RPG system in use) they will be easy to sell and value will fluctuate some based on need.
2. Trophies/memorabilia/collectables

   - Some objects have no inherent value, but are still bought and sold nonetheless. They often have value as decoration or sentimental value to a specific person. Again, generally, they're likely to be more difficult to sell and would vary greatly in value from one place to another.